# No operator >> matches these operands... why?

Tags: c++, file, vector, fstream

I'm having some problems reading a vector of ints from a file... and it's the first time this happens to me and I have tried everything.
Here is a part of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>


int m;
std::vector<int>a[100];
std::vector<int>b[100];
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("data.in");
    file>>m;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i<m/2; i++ )
         file>>a[i]>>b[i]; 



    return 0;
}
```

Why won't it work? :(

Comment: You never check that your file stream opened successfully or that your inputs succeeded.

Comment: You should really by reading in an `std::string` and use a `cast` to turn it into the type you want.

Comment: What happens?  Are *any* elements from the file read (like just the first) or it *nothing* read?  Does it exit with error code 0, or some other code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>a[100];
```

declares an array containing 100 vectors. So `a[i]` is a vector, not an `int`. You can't read a vector directly from input.

If you want vectors of *size* 100, instead of an array of 100 vectors, the syntax is

```
std::vector<int> a(100);
```

Comment: +1 you could also mention that `std::vector<int> a{100}` gives a vector with a single element 100 (in C++11).